# Ember.js Routes - Best Way to Filter By a Different Model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to create a route structure where I can view a list of all members (/members) or filter them by group (members/group-slug-to-filter-by). I have a Member model as well as a Group model, as well as the following routes:

```
this.resource('members', function() {
    this.route('/');
    this.route('group', { path: ':group_slug' });
});
```

My MembersGroup route looks like this:

```
var MembersGroupRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        // Just have this here temporarily for testing purposes,
        // but ultimately this is where I would filter by group slug
        return this.store.find('member').then(function(models) {
            return models.slice(0, 2);
        });
    },

    serialize: function(model) {
        return { 'group_slug': model.get('slug') };
    }
});
```

Essentially I have a bulleted list displaying each of the groups, and a link-to that I want to pass a group model into:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    {{#each group in groups}}
        <li>{{#link-to 'members.group' group class="list-group-item"}}{{group.name}} <span class="badge">{{group.memberCount}}</span>{{/link-to}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

When doing it this way, I'm providing a model to the link-to helper, and it therefore transitions to the members.group route without executing the model hook; this is a problem because I can't take the passed-in group model, re-execute the model hook, and filter by the group's slug.

If I pass in the group slug (as a string, rather than the group model) the model hook is executed and the list is filtered:

```
<li>{{#link-to 'members.group' group.slug class="list-group-item"}}{{group.name}} <span class="badge">{{group.memberCount}}</span>{{/link-to}}</li>
```

What is the best way to go about this functionality? Should I restructure my routes, just continue passing in the group slug, or is there a way to get this to work while passing in the group model?

I'm pretty sure I could just use actions on the links to filter by the group model, but I want to have the URL reflect the group that is being filtered (ie. members/group-slug).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll generally be passing in the slug, rather than the filtered group (presumably because you don't have access to the filtered group from where the link-to), consider making the slug the model of the route. At the controller level, you'll want the model to actually be the filtered group, and you can use the `setupController` hook to do this. In this case, you wouldn't need to define `model` or `serialize` hooks, and your route could look something like the following:

```
var MembersGroupRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        slug = model;
        controller.set 'model', this.store.find('member', groupSlug: slug).then(function(models) {
            return models.slice(0, 2);
        });
    }
});
```

Then you would call your routes the second way you present above:

```
<li>{{#link-to 'members.group' group.slug class="list-group-item"}}{{group.name}}
```

---

You could also do a similar thing and have the unfiltered group as the model in the model hook, and as what gets passed in via link-to's, and then use the `setupController` hook to filter members by this group before setting the model of the controller.

So that would be:

```
var MembersGroupRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('group', slug: params.group_slug)
    },
    serialize: function(model) {
        return { 'group_slug': model.get('slug') };
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        group = model;
        controller.set 'model', this.store.find('member', group: group)
    }
});
```

And you call routes in the first way you present above:

```
 <li>{{#link-to 'members.group' group class="list-group-item"}}{{group.name}} <span class="badge">{{group.memberCount}}</span>{{/link-to}}</li>
```